# Regex to select text without white spaces with restrictions

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to select some text between % signs where there is not white space between 2 %.

This should match:

```
%link%
```

This shouldn't:

```
%my link%
```

This easy regex would do the trick:

```
/%\S*%/g
```

But there is a catch: I can add a prefix: % and a suffix: % but the regex must contain this between these: (.+?)
(it's a third party script).

So this is the regex I need to adjust:

```
/%(.+?)%/
```

Because of "(.+?)" I need a workaround, any idea?

UPDATE:
All of these are true for a perfect regex:

```
regex = /%(.+?)%/g // default regex which allows spaces so it's not good

regex.test('%link%')
regex.test('%my link%') === false
regex.toString().includes('(.+?)')
```

Comment: You probay want `/%[^\s%]+%/g` or  `/%([^\s%]+)%/g`

Comment: Please pay attention to this:
"But there is a catch: I can add a prefix: % and a suffix: % but the regex must contain this between these: (.+?) (it's a third party script)."

Comment: Yes, what does that mean, by the way? Check https://regex101.com/r/86NsNn/1

Comment: Please clarify your intent. Do you mean you do not want to match `##link#` or `#link##`? Then use `/(?<!%)%([^\s%]+)%(?!%)/g`

Comment: Or perhaps match one or more `%` at the left and right can capture what is in between `%+([^\s%]+)%+` https://regex101.com/r/vshKJg/1

Comment: Thank you all for your comments but you are missing the most important thing: I can only set the beginning and the end of the regex because it's in a third party script. The perfect regex must contain this: (.+?)
I updated my original question

Comment: `new RegExp("%(?=[^\\s%]+%)" + "(.+?)" + "%", "g")`? See https://regex101.com/r/86NsNn/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
var some_hardcoded_value = ".+?";
var regex = new RegExp("%(?=[^\\s%]+%)" + some_hardcoded_value + "%", "g");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/86NsNn/3).

*Details*:

- `%` - a `%` char
- `(?=[^\s%]+%)` - a positive lookahead that requires any one or more chars other than whitespace and `%` immediately to the right of the current location
- `(.+?)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than line break chars
- `%` - a`%` char.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const some_hardcoded_value = ".+?";
const regex = new RegExp("%(?=[^\\s%]+%)(" + some_hardcoded_value + ")%", "g");
const str = "%link% This shouldn't %my link%  %%link,,,,,%%%%";
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), x => x[1]));
```